# SFML only draws some sprites

Tags: c++, drawing, sfml

I'm having a strange problem where one sprite is loading however another isn't

Here is my main.cpp

```
    window.draw(universe.getPlayer()->draw());  //Draw Player

    std::list<AbstractBlock*>::const_iterator i;
    std::list<AbstractBlock*>* values = universe.getLoadedBlocks();

    for (i = values->begin(); i != values->end(); ++i){
        window.draw((*i)->draw()); //Draw Blocks
    }

    window.display();
```

Here you can see the player drawing and all the blocks in the universe drawing. However, only the player draws and the blocks don't draw at all. I have made sure that the loop is actually working. However because draw() returns void I can't actually see if its working or not.

Here is the DirtBlock.cpp (I'm inheriting from AbstractBlock)

```
DirtBlock::DirtBlock(int x, int y, float rotation, b2World *world){
    bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
    bodyDef.linearDamping = .03f;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    fixDef.density = .1f;

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(16, 16);

    fixDef.shape = &shape;

    body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    body->CreateFixture(&fixDef);

    texture.loadFromFile("Dirt.bmp");

    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setOrigin(16, 16);


}

sf::Sprite DirtBlock::draw(){
    sprite.setPosition(body->GetPosition().x, body->GetPosition().y);
    return sprite;
}
```

Not everything is included, only the stuff that is involved with the drawing.

My Player class is very similar:

```
Player::Player(b2World *world){

    texture.loadFromFile("player.bmp");
    bodyDef.position.Set(10, 10);
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    fixDef.density = .1f;
    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(16, 16);
    fixDef.shape = &shape;

    body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    body->CreateFixture(&fixDef);
    body->SetLinearDamping(.03f);

    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setOrigin(16, 16);

    force = 10.f;

}

sf::Sprite Player::draw(){
    sprite.setPosition(body->GetPosition().x, body->GetPosition().y);
    sprite.setRotation(body->GetAngle() * (180 / b2_pi));
    return sprite;
}
```

Since they are so similar why is one drawing and the other not? I have a feeling it might be because of my inheritance. I'm typically a Java programmer and I'm not 100% sure I did the inheritance correctly in C++. Should it be like this? (My DirtBlock.h)

```
class DirtBlock: public AbstractBlock
{
public:
    DirtBlock();
    DirtBlock(int x, int y, float rotation, b2World *world);
    ~DirtBlock();
    virtual sf::Sprite draw();
    virtual void destroy(b2World *world);
private: 
    sf::Sprite sprite;
};
```

Comment: Could it be possible that your texture is loading incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it myself. It turned out to be a stupid mistake on my part but I might as well write and answer so if anyone else makes this mistake they may find this and it may fix their problem.

I didn't make the function `draw` in the AbstractBlock class `virtual`. Because of this, when I was calling draw for the DirtBlock, it was looking for the draw method in AbstractBlock that didn't have a virtual flag.